# Importance of ethernet connector and using a different connector with it

Tags: ethernet

I'm working on designing a modular system where a custom camera has a mounting plate that screws on to a mounting plate on a robot. The camera gets power from the robot over springloaded pins built into the mounting plate that contact pads on the mounting plate of the robot. The camera uses ethernet to send video back, is it possible to use this same connection scheme, springloaded pins and pads, to connect the ethernet from the camera to the robot? The overall run of ethernet is <1 foot.
Thanks,

Comment: For 100-base-t, definitely. For gigabit probably.

Comment: Ideally, you should choose a connector system designed for high speed differential signaling. But it will probably work no matter what connector you use.